# What is a temporary CLOB in buffer cache for?

Tags: oracle, blob, clob

The `dbms_lob.createtemporary` function takes three parameters, one of which specifies if the temporary LOB is to be "read into buffer cache or not". I'm not entirely clear on what that means. More importantly, when do i want my LOB in the buffer cache and when do I not want it there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically if the same lob is going to be accessed several times, it will improve performance if the lob is in the cache.

see: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28393/adlob_tables.htm

From the link above 'Using the CACHE option results in improved performance when reading and writing data from the LOB column. However, it can potentially age other non-LOB pages out of the buffer cache prematurely.'

Answer (score 2):

In simple words, that means to be in memory. 
I don't know how much stays there, but almost sure is put there at creation.
Learn [here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/concepts/cache.html) some concepts.